# Evaluation Metrics for Generative Adversarial Networks

Tags: metrics, generative-adversarial-network

I'm using GANs on non image data, and I'm looking for some qualitative metrics to measure the quality of the generated samples.

I can't use Inception Score (IS) or similar metrics that uses inception model because I'm not working on images.

Is there any metrics which are clearly explained ?